# Generic Type Typings Not Behaving as Expected

Tags: java, generics, abstract-class

I have three `abstract` `class`es:

`public abstract class Shader`

`public abstract class ShaderInput`

`public abstract class ShaderOutput`

The body of the `Shader` class is very simple:

```
    protected Function<ShaderInput, ShaderOutput> shader;

    public Shader(Function<ShaderInput, ShaderOutput> shader){
        this.shader = shader;
    }

    public ShaderOuput render(ShaderInput input){
        return shader.apply(input);
    }
```

I then have a `VertexShader` which `extends Shader`,

a `VertexInput` which `extends ShaderInput`,

and a `VertexOutput` which `extends ShaderOutput`

What I don't understand is why my constructor in my `VertexShader` class cannot be written as follows:

```
public VertexShader(Function<VertexInput, VertexOutput> vertexShader){
     super(vertexShader);
}
```

When I type the incoming `Function` as above, the IDE complains that

`The constructor Shader(Function<VertexInput,VertexOutput>) is undefined`

I would assume that because `VertexInput extends ShaderInput` and `VertexOutput extends ShaderOutput` that this would work and be able to provide more readability to the code.

Comment: What language are you using? I'm guessing Java because of `super`?

Comment: Oh thanks, I forgot to tag the lang, I barely ever ask questions

Comment: I have tried playing around with different ways to wild card bound it, but to no avail.

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot be written as follows"? Do you get a compiler error? If yes, please show it. Does it compile but doesn't work? Please explain the expected behavior vs. the actual one.

Comment: @Sentry  edited my question

Comment: (the words to google are "covariant" and "contravariant")

Answer (score 2):

In your code, it would be possible to call `render` with any `ShaderInput`, e.g. of class `SpecialInput extends ShaderInput`, which is not compatible with `VertexInput`.

What you can do is change your classes like this:

```
public abstract class Shader<T extends ShaderInput, U extends ShaderOutput> {

  protected Function<T, U> shader;

  public Shader(Function<T, U> shader) {
    this.shader = shader;
  }

  public U render(T input) {
    return shader.apply(input);
  }
}
```

and

```
public class VertexShader extends Shader<VertexInput, VertexOutput> {

  public VertexShader(Function<VertexInput, VertexOutput> vertexShader) {
    super(vertexShader);
  }

}
```

Also see:

- [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po)
- [Java: using generic wildcards with subclassing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626317/java-using-generic-wildcards-with-subclassing)

Comment: why not directly say `public U render(T input) {`

Comment: @Lino Thanks, I missed that

Comment: you might also want to change the `Function<T, U>` to `Function<? super T, ? extends U>` which is more reliable. because a `Function<? super VertexInput, ? extends VertexOutput>` would not be allowed to be passed to `Shader` constructor

Comment: @Lino I'm sure you're right, but I can't quite follow your train of thought. Feel free to edit my answer, though, if it preserves correctness ;)

Comment: A `Function<? super VertexInput, ? extends VertexOutput>` can accept a type that extends a `VertexInput` but which is not known and produces a Type that extends `VertexOutput` but which is also not known. This is a problem in the fact that you can't assign that `function` to `Function<VertexInput, VertexOutput>`. Maybe have a look yourself at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super). Which should help you understand my point